# How do I get data attributes in javascript?

Tags: javascript

So, I want to get a data-price attribute from an element. I do not want to use jQuery(simply because it looks really complex to install, for something very simple I want to do). How can I do this? I found no way to do it in javascript. I've tried just dotting after the element variable.

Comment: `document.getElementById('element').getAttribute('data-price')`

Comment: jQuery does not require installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`element.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset) will get you the set of an element’s `data-*` attributes, if supported, so:

```
element.dataset.price
```

On browsers where this isn’t supported, you can use the usual `.getAttribute('data-price')` and cast appropriately.

Comment: I never knew dataset existed thanks for the enlightenment, it's a shame IE has only just started supporting it.